# Remove and destroy a set of AngularJS elements and scopes added by a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, dom-manipulation

I need some help or advice on how to remove ALL elements and destroy ALL Angular scopes added by isolated directive.

I have an isolated directive that adds rows of HTML forms to the DOM when called by some other function e.g. `ng-click="AddForm()"`.

So far I've been able to remove individual elements and destroy it's scope:

`ng-click="deleteSearchFilter($event)"`.

**What I want to do now is remove ALL elements and scopes.** For instance, lets say I added 5 rows of forms and now I want to delete all of them at once when I click on a button e.g. `ng-click="deleteAll()"`.

I don't know where to begin. Below is a piece of code that demonstrates deleting individual elements and scopes. My initial approach is to define an array in the parent scope and push a new object every time a new element is added to the DOM. I don't know where to go from here.

```
//newSearchFilter Directive
  app.directive('newSearchFilter', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:{ searchFilterForm: "=",
              elementsArray: "="
       }, //New isolated scope => reusable directive
      templateUrl: '/core/products/new_search_filter.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        //When a new form is added increment searchFilterForm.counter
        var x = ++scope.searchFilterForm.counter;
        console.log('elements-array lenght inside link function is',  scope.elementsArray.length);
        scope.elementsArray.push({index: x, scope: scope, element: element});
        console.log('scope.elementsArray',  scope.elementsArray);
      },
      controller: function($scope, $element){
        //Function gets a click $event
        $scope.deleteSearchFilter = function(e){
          //Removes element and also destroys the scope
          //Recommended way of doing this type of things
          $element.remove();
          $scope.$destroy();
          //when a form is deleted decrement searchFilterForm.counter
          var decrementCounter = --$scope.searchFilterForm.counter;
          console.log('elements-array length inside controller function is',  $scope.elementsArray.length);

        }
      }
    };
  });
```

newSearchFilter directive HTML template. The template is very dirty as it contains lots of UI logic. This is my first iteration and will improve it.

```
<form id="new-search-filter-{{searchFilterForm.counter}}" ng-controller="productsFormFilterBuilderCtrl">
   <div class="row">
      <!-- Filter products on Product Name, Product Description etc  -->
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="filter_field" id="filter_field"
               ng-options="option.name for option in default_form.options track by option.id"
               ng-model="default_form.selected_option">
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Display only for Product Name, Description and Status-->
      <div ng-if="default_form.selected_option.name == 'Product Name' || 
         default_form.selected_option.name == 'Product Description' ||
         default_form.selected_option.name == 'Status'" >
         <!-- Filter on Product Name -->
         <div class="col-md-3" ng-if="default_form.selected_option.name == 'Product Name' ">
            <div class="form-group">
               <select class="form-control" name="product_name" id="product_name"
                  ng-options="option.name for option in product_name.operators track by option.id"
                  ng-model="product_name.selected_option">
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Filter on Product Description -->
         <div class="col-md-3" ng-if="default_form.selected_option.name == 'Product Description' ">
            <div class="form-group">
               <select class="form-control" name="product_description " id="product_description "
                  ng-options="option.name for option in product_description.operators track by option.id"
                  ng-model="product_description.selected_option">
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Filter on Product Status-->
         <div class="col-md-3" ng-if="default_form.selected_option.name == 'Status'">
            <div class="form-group">
               <select class="form-control" name="status_operators" id="status_operators"
                  ng-options="option.name for option in status_options.operators track by option.id"
                  ng-model="status_options.selected_option">
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group" id="filter_input1">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_value" placeholder="Enter Value" name="input" ng-model="input.text">
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- delete button-->
         <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
            <div class="form-group">
               <a ng-click="deleteSearchFilter($event)"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i></a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Filters when End Date is selected. Attach datePicker controller here -->
      <div ng-if="default_form.selected_option.name == 'End Date'" ng-controller="datePickerCtrl">
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
               <select class="form-control" name="date_operators" id="date_operators"
                  ng-options="option.name for option in end_date_options.operators track by option.id"
                  ng-model="end_date_options.selected_option"></select>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Filter when End Date is selected and Equal, Does Not Equal,
            Is Greater Than/or Equal To is selected-->
         <div ng-if="end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Equal' || 
            end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Does Not Equal' || 
            end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Is Greater Than' ||
            end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Is Greater Than Or Equal To' ">
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Display end date datepicker for 'Is Less Than' or 'Is Less Than or Equal To'-->
         <div ng-if="end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Is Less Than' 
            || end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Is Less Than Or Equal To'">
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Displays two day pickers if 'End Date' && 'Is Between' is selected -->
         <div ng-if="end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Is Between'" ng-controller="datePickerCtrl">
            <div class="col-md-2">
               <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
               <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- delete button-->
         <div ng-if="end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Equal' || 
            end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Does Not Equal' || 
            end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Is Greater Than' ||
            end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Is Greater Than Or Equal To' || 
            end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Is Less Than' 
            || end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Is Less Than Or Equal To'">
            <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <a ng-click="deleteSearchFilter($event)"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i></a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

         <div ng-if="end_date_options.selected_option.name == 'Is Between'">
            <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <a ng-click="deleteSearchFilter($event)"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i></a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide the template HTML for `newSearchFilter`.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein the HTML template for newSearchFilter is very dirty as it contains lots of UI logic. I plan on using the schemaform AngularJS  plugin [http://schemaform.io/] to make it more readable and maintainable.